# why I tried everything said in the site and I got nowhere with "emulator did not connect within 60 seconds " for Flutter?

Tags: android, visual-studio, flutter, powershell, android-emulator

Sorry ,I am novice to Flutter .I am trying to install android emulator for Flutter and I get an error .I know this question was some how repeated but I tried everything presented as solution in this site and other sites and I got no where. I changed Bios for visualization ,wiped emulator data even deleted and re-installed emulator on Android Studio.Re-stared whole system and software,installed HAMX etc.It is 2 days and I got nowhere with this issue.Can you help please?  There isn't that much code to show here .The main problem is the error that I mentioned "emulator did not connect within 60 seconds ". I installed Flutter from a Youtube video instruction .But I rectified all the errors except this one. and I checked in Windows Powershell to make sure there is no error .FYI: no emulator screen pops up as demo .I have basically nothing as emulator .  I have Windows.It is not any other OS.

guys any answer that can help?I really spent so much time set this up and now I am stuck!!running Windows Powershell shows no error either.I use Windows 8.1 and I have to folders for android studio ,one in C:\ and one in c:\program file.I am not sure if this had caused a problem .

Comment: have you tried using a phone instead of emulator?

Comment: yeah I did it but I am not sure why I should not be able to do it through emulator!! when I connected the phone it gave me this error."

PS C:\Users\isan\Desktop\flutter project\flutter_novice> flutter devices
2 connected devices:

Chrome (web) • chrome • web-javascript • Google Chrome 92.0.4515.131
Edge (web)   • edge   • web-javascript • Microsoft Edge 92.0.902.67
• Device 5203fe5be2273427 is not authorized.(this is the phone I assume)
You might need to check your device for an authorization dialog."                         I allowed access via phone ,developer mode is on

Comment: I had to allow using "phone as source " instead of other options "file transfer etc". now it shows in Visual Studio but no demo or picture of cell phone shows up on my computer!!   it shows a device recognized by VS but it does not show the emulator image .and of course my other question is even if I get image of cell phone should I connect phone each time I wanna use Flutter?

Comment: it will not show you the image of cell phone, and make sure to check authorization dialog when you connect your phone. After that you should be able to run and debug your apps. have you installed another emulator"

Comment: it gave me this error when trying to run debug 
"*FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
Gradle could not start your build.
 Could not create service of type ResourceSnapshotterCacheService using GradleUserHomeServices.createResourceSnapshotterCacheService().
 Timeout waiting to lock file hash cache (C:\Users\....\.gradle\caches\6.7\fileHashes). It is currently in use by another Gradle instance.
     Owner PID: 6184
     Our PID: 6848
     Owner Operation: 
     Our operation: " as I said no image of emulator on screen either .I did not create any other emulator

Comment: also this is rest of error in debug console                                                                "Lock file: C:\Users\...\.gradle\caches\6.7\fileHashes\fileHashes.lock

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights."

Comment: delete .lock files in gradle caches or .gradle folder to make gradle work.

Comment: this site says avoid more comment .I do not understand the problem with commenting!!and it does not allow chat either . I may have to put my stuff in answers . I looked into Gradle folder ,there was not any .lock file in it .there is a lib folder inside gradle and then all kinds of ".jar" files such as gradle-toolling,gradle-extention etc. with .jar suffix)

Comment: i meant this folder C:\Users\...\.gradle and its sub folders

Comment: In main folder I did not find anything. In specific file folder I found it and removed it . But it did not work anyways. It gave me other errors. I really do not understand what the purpose of connecting phone is!!! Can you tell me about that? I really need virtual emulator ,not phone image.it should not be this hard. I have seen YouTube tutorials that people install emulator  without even opening Android Studio.It was very fast.

Answer (score 0):

Guys any other ways to solve this? I reinstalled VS, Flutter and Dart too, turned off antivirus, checked no proxy etc. I need to get this done to start working with Flutter